# how to use gocardless.com with django

Tags: django, payment-gateway, gocardless

I have to use gocardless payment gateway with Django, How can I use this with my project.

are there any good django packages ,which support this latest gocardless payments,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the python gocardless package in django

Installation:

```
pip install gocardless_pro
```

Implementation:

```
import gocardless_pro
import os
client = gocardless_pro.Client(
    access_token=os.environ['GC_ACCESS_TOKEN'], 
    environment='sandbox'
)
print(client.customers.list().records)
```

To get started learning the GoCardless API, read through the tutorial with python code samples at https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/api/introduction/?lang=python